# Checking if iOS app was launched from local notification?

Tags: ios, notifications

How do you detect if an app that is NOT in an active, inactive, or background state (terminated) is launched from a local notification? So far, I've tried two methods in the App Delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // METHOD 1:
    if let options = launchOptions {
        if let key = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] {
            notificationCenter.postNotification(NSNotification(name: "applicationLaunchedFromNotification", object: nil))
        }
    }

    // METHOD 2:
    let notification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as! UILocalNotification!
    if (notification != nil) {
        notificationCenter.postNotification(NSNotification(name: "applicationLaunchedFromNotification", object: nil))
    }

    return true
}
```

In my View Controller, I observe for the notification in ViewDidLoad and in response, set a UILabel's text:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "handleAppLaunchFromNotification", name: "applicationLaunchedFromNotification", object: nil)
}

func handleAppLaunchFromNotification() {
    debugLabel.text = "app launched from notification"
}
```

But the UILabel's text is never set after launching the terminated app from a local notification.

My questions are:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is there an easier way to debug a situation like this other than setting a UILabel? Once the app is terminated, Xcode's debugger detaches the app and I can't use `print()`.

Comment: Well, that depends whether the observer for the notification was set before the NSNotification was posted.

Comment: How do I ensure that? Does an observer set in `viewDidLoad` persist even after an app is terminated? Right now: the view loads and sets up an observer, the user presses a button in that view to set a notification, and the notification is fired at a future date. I want to be able to respond to the user launching the app from that notification when it fires. I'm not sure if it matters, but I've explicitly opted my app out of backgrounding in the Info.plist file. So, the app terminates upon hitting the home button (no backgrounding).

Answer (score 0):

You are checking local notification in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` this methods contains `launchOptions` for only remote notifications. If app is in terminated state and you perform action on local notification then `didReceiveLocalNotification` gets call after `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your post. As per Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Launch_Options_Keys), there exists `launchOptions` for local notifications. Can I not use this?

Comment: have you found the solution ?